# Tensorflow installation error on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tensorflow, installation

When verifying my tensorflow installation as per the instructions here: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#ValidateYourInstallation

I get the following error message immediately after importing tf:

```
(tensorflow) Davids-iMac:~ david$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr 24 2017, 06:18:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
python(12966,0x7fffa84273c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10b235eb0: 
pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I have had this problem on two different Macs; this installation was in a virtualenv, the other installation python directly. I installed python 3, readline and pip from scratch with Macports using sudo -H.

I also used sudo port select --set python python36 to set python3 to be the default (same for pip3).

### Any hints where I went wrong greatly appreciated.

Here the virtualenv installation of tf: 
    cd /opt/local/bin
    sudo ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv
    cd

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 tensorflow/
The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist
Davids-iMac:~ david$ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python tensorflow/
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/local/bin/python
Using base prefix '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/david/tensorflow/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Davids-iMac:~ david$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
(tensorflow) Davids-iMac:~ david$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/david/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages     (python 3.6)
(tensorflow) Davids-iMac:~ david$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl (31.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 31.3MB 49kB/s 
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading numpy-1.12.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (4.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.4MB 319kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in ./tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 317kB 3.0MB/s 
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.2.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading protobuf-3.3.0.tar.gz (271kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 3.2MB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow)
Building wheels for collected packages: protobuf
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for protobuf ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/david/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/1b/42/a0/4c7343df5b629ec9c75655468dce7652b28026896b0209ba55
Successfully built protobuf
Installing collected packages: numpy, werkzeug, six, protobuf, tensorflow
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.1 protobuf-3.3.0 six-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.12.2
(tensorflow) Davids-iMac:~ david$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr 24 2017, 06:18:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
python(12966,0x7fffa84273c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10b235eb0:     pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: We build our tensorflow binaries using the python 3 from brew. Your build may be incompatible due to differences in the python library itself or its dependents.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Why would the import itself fail? This would imply that brew python libraries can't be used by macports python, which would be news to me. I'm not saying you're wrong, just that it's surprising.