# Illegal instruction: 4 when importing tensorflow in python 3.6

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I installed [Tensorflow on macOS](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) with Virtualenv. Everything went okay ("Successfully installed six-1.11.0 tensorflow-1.6.0" is the last output of the terminal, once i run the command `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`). So, with the virtualenv activated, I typed: `python3` and then `import tensorflow as tf`
but it outputs the error `Illegal instruction: 4` and quits python.

I looked around to see if anybody else had encountered the same issue, but I didn't find much, apart from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362407/tensorflow-installation-error-on-mac-osx-sierra) question, which doesn't provide a solution. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10) answer explaining what Illegal instruction means, the point is that I'm on the latest version of macOS High Sierra:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding what the answer is referring to?

Do you know how I could solve this issue? Or hopefully a workaround, so that I can start using tensorflow.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: figure it out? yet I am experiencing same thing, i see you installed 1.6 me too. I will revert back to 1.5 and see

Comment: so I installed 1.15, and I was getting a warning about deprecating features in numpy. so after installing tensorflow 1.15, I installed numpy 1.13. everything works ok now

Comment: error was: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

Comment: It seems to be working on my end as well. Plus, since it is in a virtualenv the rest of my machine still has the latest numpy version. Thank you so much for the help! It’s the workaround I was looking for. So if you’d like, you could write an answer so that I can mark it as the correct one

Comment: thanks, i added an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, so what I did was uninstalled tensorflow 1.6. installed

```
pip install -Iv tensorflow==1.5
pip install -Iv numpy==1.13
```

seems to be fine now, my guess is there was the latest bug in tensorflow 1.6.

To make sure it's compatible with the pandas, you can do:
   pip install -Iv numpy==1.13.3

Answer (score 3):

It could not find 1.15 version for me as for @dfresh22, but that helped:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install -Iv tensorflow==1.5
```

Comment: thanks, haha just realized it was a typo. I just updated the answer to 1.5. thanks for the heads up

Comment: @dfresh22 I also did not need to install `numpy=1.13`, I have currently `numpy (1.14.2)` and it worked well!

Comment: Interesting. I will check the latest tensorflow and see. Have been working on MASK RCNN lately. Super fun.

Comment: Solved it for me on a good old 2011 macbook pro and El capitan

Answer (score 2):

Similarly, on Apple M1 with BigSur (Python 3.9), the Anaconda interface did complain about incompatible version of tensorflow for Python 3.9, pip did install from the terminal but I got "illegal instruction:4" message. Finally, the following command sorted out the necessary packages to install:

```
conda install conda-forge::tensorflow
```

the detail is [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/apple-silicon-transition). This installation is an older version of tensorflow: tensorflow-2.7.0 .

Comment: I am on MacBook M2 pro max and this conda install is the only thing that worked for me. None of the pip installation commands work as after when I try to import tensorflow I get the Illegal instruction: 4 error all the time. Strange that tenforflow officially recommend to use pip when it doesn't work for Mac.

Comment: What's the difference between `conda install conda-forge::tensorflow` and `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`?

Comment: @HermanAutore. It is just a shorthand usage.