# How to fix Illegal Instruction: 4 when trying to run a python file in MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, dlib

I am trying to install dlib and run the code from [here](https://github.com/raviranjan0309/Detect-Facial-Features).
After installing dlib when I execute the line

```
python detect_face_features.py --shape-predictor shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat --image images/image_1.jpg
```

I get the error
`Illegal instruction: 4`

I tried creating a virtual environment first and install dlib and opencv. The files get imported but on running the code on python I get the same error. I clean installed it on my root environment but still the same error. I can't figure out what library or file is broken as other python files work as expected.
I am working on MacOS 10.11.6 with XCode version 8.2.1
I installed the dlib with reference to [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/) site.

Please tell me how to fix this. Thank you.

Edit: My MacBook is of mid 2010 build and it doesn't have AVX instructions built into it. I tried installing dlib again by explicitly switching off AVX instructions but the problem still persists.

```
sudo python3 setup.py install --no USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
```

I also tried [this](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/11) solution but couldn't find the line

```
set(USE_SSE4_INSTRUCTIONS ON CACHE BOOL "Use SSE4 instructions")
```

on dlib's path tools/python/CMakeLists.txt

Please tell me how can I fix this issue.
Thank You.

Comment: Maybe is related to the version of the packages you are using? I have seen this with many numerical modules, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084934/illegal-instruction-4-when-importing-tensorflow-in-python-3-6

Comment: @cmaureir How do I check which versions are causing the trouble?